# deduce lim of f(x) from lim f'(x)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$  and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f''(x)=k$ how to prove that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{1+x}=k$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}=\frac{k}{2}$

i think about using Hopital's rule but i have problem if $k=0$.

Thank you

Comment: I might be missing something, but what's the problem if $k = 0$? L'Hopital's rule seems like a very sensible approach here.

Comment: @TheoBendit how to write it please

Comment: I don't think there's any trick to it. Just write it as you were going to, except don't worry about the $k = 0$, as I can't see any reason why it should be singular in any way. For example, you can say, by L'Hopital's rule that, because $\frac{f''(x)}{1} \to k$, we have $\frac{f'(x)}{1 + x} \to k$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

If $f''$ is not integrable on $(a,\infty)$ (so $\int_a^b f''\,\mathrm dx$ noes not converge at $b\to\infty$) then since $f''$ converges if $k\neq 0$ then $f''(x)$ is positive or negative for all sufficiently large $x$. Then $f'(x)-f'(0) = \int_0^x f''\,\mathrm d x$ diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Then you can use de L’Hospital. Now, if $k=0$ it *might* be that $f'(x)$ diverges to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$, but it does not nescessarily need to be this way. But if we take a sequence so that $f'(x_n)$ converges against the limsup/liminf, then eighter this limsup/liminf is finite, by which $f'(x)/(1+x)$ goes to $0$, or they are not finite, so you can use de L’Hostpital to get that for both limsup and liminf the limit of $f'(x_n)/(1+x_n)$ is $k=0$. For any other sequence it will be bounded by these sequences, so the limit is $k=0$.

On the other hand, if $f'(x)$ converges, then clearly $k=0$ and $f'(x)/(1+x)$ converges to $0$.

For the second one you can use the same argument. If $k\neq 0$ then $f'$ and thus $f$ diverges against $\infty$ or $-\infty$, so you can use de L’Hospital. If it is $0$ then you simply use sequences for limsup and liminf, and if $f(x)$ converges the result is trivial.

EDIT: It remains to argue that if $f'/g'$ converges then the proof of de l’Hospital can be used for sequences: If $f(x_n),g(x_n)\to 0$ then
$$ f(x_n)/g(x_n) = f'(\xi)/g'(\xi) $$
for some $\xi$ between $x_0$ and $x_n$. Then with $x_n\to x_0$ we get the result.

Comment: i don't understand how you start : if f'' is not integrable?

Comment: @Vrouvrou This is meant in regard with the improper integral $\int_a^\infty$.

Comment: i don't understand the case $k=0$, how we take a sequence $x_n$ why we can choose a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f'(x_n)$ converge ?

Comment: i don't understand the case k=0 @Lazy

Comment: @Vrouvrou We are considering all the limit points of $f'$, that is, all points $y$ so that there is a sequence $x_n\to\infty$ with $f'(x_n)\to y$ (and potentiall $\pm\infty$). Then this set has a sup/inf, which we consider the limsup/liminf. By taking a diagonal sequence one can easily construct a sequence $(x_n)$ so that $f'(x_n)$ converges towards this limsup/liminf (or diverge towards $\pm\infty$).

Comment: @Vrouvrou Which is easy to see: If $(x_n^k)$ is a sequence of sequences so that $\lim_n f'(x_n^k) \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} a $ for some $a$, then we take $y_n = x_n^n$. As long as we assume that $f'(x_n^k)$ converges fast enough (which can be achieved by subsetting) we can achieve that $|f'(x_n^k) - \lim_n f'(x_n^k)| < 1/n$ and $|a-\lim_n f'(x_n^k)| < 1/k$. Then $|a-f'(y_n)|<2/n$.

Comment: @Vrouvrou Also by subsetting we can easily guarantee the $x_n^k \geq n$, so that $y_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130303/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-lazy).

Comment: There is no need to check behavior of numerator while applying L'Hospital's Rule here. If denominator tends to $\infty $ we can just apply the rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That is

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to prove itfor just derivatives of order 1 and $k>0$. Ican do this without loss  of generality since for higher order derivatives I can iteratively apply the first order case, while for $k<0$ I can use $-f'(x)$ with the same idea.

**For $k>0$:**
If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = k \implies (\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists x_0>0)~~ \text{s.t. if} ~ x>x_0 ~ \text{then} ~ |f(x) - k| < \epsilon$. 
This also means that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{\infty} f'(x) dx = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{\infty} (f'(x)-k+k) dx \ge f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{\infty} (k-\epsilon) dx = \infty ~~ \text{if we choose} ~\epsilon~ \text{to be smaller than } k$$

So we proved that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$. Now since this is the case that byt the l'Hopital rule:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{1+x} = \lim f'(x)$$

**For $k=0$:**
If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \pm\infty$, you can apply  the L;Hopitalrule. If not, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} {f(x)}{1+x} = 0 = $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$$

Comment: and for $k=0$ ?

Comment: Again this is unnecessary to check behavior of numerator. If denominator tends to $\infty $ you can apply L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is there any reference you can direct me to read on L'Hospital's Rule ? I seem to get on when/where to apply it and in what cases it is applicable.

Comment: @Vrouvrou I included that special case as well.

Comment: @Krosin: you can look at proof (and not just statement) given in Wikipedia.